# Getting overflow stack error when adding self-referencing entity in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .a

I have a class named category in my project. I am trying to make subcategories of categories. The category class is self-referencing. My category class.

```
public class Category : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get =>  this.Id; set => this.Id = value; }
        public int? IsSubCategoryOf { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public DateTime AddedAt { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Category> SubCategory { get; set; }
        public List<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
    }
```

My context class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne<Category>(c => c.ParentCategory).WithMany(c => c.SubCategory).HasForeignKey(c => c.IsSubCategoryOf);
            });
```

I am getting an overflow stack error while inserting data into the database. My Repository class.

```
public Category Add(Category entity)
        {
            _context.Categories.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return entity;
        }
```

How can i solve this problem?

controller class.

```
try
            {
                Category categoryDb = new Category();
                if(category.IsSubCategoryOf == -1)
                {
                    categoryDb.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;
                    categoryDb.AddedAt = category.AddedAt;
                    categoryDb.IsActive = category.IsActive;
                    _context.Categories.Add(categoryDb);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    Category parentCategoryDb = _context.Categories.Include(c => c.SubCategory).Where(c => c.Id == category.IsSubCategoryOf).FirstOrDefault();
                    categoryDb.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;
                    parentCategoryDb.SubCategory.Add(categoryDb);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                return Ok(categoryDb);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
```

Comment: I refer you to the first comment on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75173794/659190

Comment: First of all, you should make the Id an automatic property as well: `public int Id { get; set; }` just like the rest. That's probably the cause of your stack overflow exception. What you tried to do implies the existence of another private field that you use as backing field.